# Search post array in comma separated column value

Tags: php, mysql

Table - Column Data

```
id | filter_data |
---|---------------
1  |2,3,45,67,4  |
2  |2,3,55,33,5,7|
```

Post variable from form as

```
$search_filter = {2,3,4,5}
```

How can I get the `id` which are in the search filter

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad database design

Comment: will take a note next time  Thank you

Comment: You can use the function `find_in_set` to find a value in a csv in mysql

Comment: yes, but i need something like to find csv in csv

Comment: You have to split your search_filter and connect many `find_in_set` calls with `and`

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

As @Jens commented, it's a bad DB design to store values as CSV.
So the first solution would be to change your DB design since I don't really know what you're storing and what is the purpose of your DB/code I can't write a scheme or give any meaningful suggestion.

**Solution 2:**

Use MySQL's [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
> string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
> string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the
> first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type
> SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic.
> Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.
> Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work
> properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(searchFilterHere, filter_data)
```

**Solution 3:**

You can use the `LIKE` operator. (Some members probably will kill me for suggesting it, but if you don't want to change your DB design - this is a creative option).

Let's check the following code:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE filter_data LIKE '%2,%'
```

The problem is that it will return the id of a field with `22,` in the filter_data's column.
Therefore, you'll have to change the data under that column so `,` will appear also as the first and last characters.
For instance:

```
id | filter_data   |
---|---------------
1  |,2,3,45,67,4,  |
2  |,2,3,55,33,5,7,|
```

And now you can do the following:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE filter_data LIKE '%,2,%'
```

If you have multiple "search filters" you can combine the `LIKE`s with an `OR` operator.