# How select an array in associate array on the basic on some value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $arrItems['items'] in which 5 more arrays (associate array) and each array contain 5 element (`with the keys: f_name, l_name, contact, address, seller_id`).

I want to get all those arrays (from $arrItems['items']) in which element of seller_id is 1 like `"seller_id"=>"1,2,3"` OR `"seller_id"=>"3,2,1"` OR `"seller_id"=>"4,6,2"` OR `"seller_id"=>"5,3,4"` OR `"seller_id"=>"2,1,2"`  Array given below.

```
array(5)
{
  [0] =>
    array(5)
    {
      ["f_name"] =>
        string(3) "abc"
      ["l_name"] =>
        string(3) "xyz"
      ["contact"] =>
        string(5) "12345"
      ["address"] =>
        string(3) "xyz"
      ["seller_id"] =>
        string(1) => "1,2,3"
    }
  [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["f_name"]=>
        string(3) "abc"
      ["l_name"]=>
        string(3) "xyz"
      ["contact"]=>
        string(5) "12345"
      ["address"]=>
        string(3) "xyz"
      ["seller_id"]=>
        string(1)=>"3,2,1"
}
[2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
      string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
      string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
      string(1)=>"4,6,2"
}
[3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
      string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
      string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
      string(1)=>"5,3,4"
}
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
      string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
      string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
      string(1)=>"2,1,2"
}
```

Kindly Help me it actually order table i want to just pick those array in which current seller id is 1 . for example `seller No # 1` is login. then all those array select mean those array save in other array.

Comment: Is this data coming from a database table? If so, you need to normalize your data structure to prevent future headaches. https://stackoverflow.com/q/30702547/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_filter` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)) with `in_array` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)):

```
$sellerId = "1";
$arr = array_filter($arrItems['items'], function($e) use ($sellerId) {
    return in_array($sellerId, explode(",", $e["seller_id"]); 
});
```

If you want only those 5 option use:

```
$options = array("1,2,3", "3,2,1", "5,3,4", "4,6,2", "2,1,2");
$arr = array_filter($arrItems['items'], function($e) use ($options ) {
    return in_array($e["seller_id"], $options); 
});
```

**Edited**: As for your request this is version of the same code using `foreach` loop:

```
$sellerId = "1";
$seller_order_arr = []; 

foreach ($arrItems['items'] as $row) { 
    if (in_array($sellerId, explode(",", $row["seller_id"])))
        $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
}
```

Now `$seller_order_arr` will hold your filtered array

Comment: dWinder ?
this solution is perfect for extracting array . 
But in my project it create problem. extracted array data not set with Grid.
 Can you extracting array using **foreach loop** ?

Comment: Any code using `array_filter` can be re-write using `for-loop` I am not near by computer now - I can do that tomorrow

Comment: dWinder ! its okay i will wait you tomorrow.
Because i try re-write code But it return those array in which seller_id 1 exist but also some more arrays return.
my Code
`  $seller_order_arr = [];
        foreach ($arrItems['items'] as  $row) {
            if (strpos($row['current_seller_id'] ,",") > 1 && $row['current_seller_id'] != null){
                $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
            }
            if($row['current_seller_id'] == $currentUser){
                $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
            }
        }
        $arrItems['items'] = $seller_order_arr;`


Thanks

Comment: @HaFizUmer Added version on the code with `foreach` loop

Comment: I re-write array_filter code into foreach. 
Check 
`$seller_order_arr = [];
        foreach ($arrItems['items'] as  $row) {
            if ($row['current_seller_id'] != null){
                if (in_array($currentUser, explode(",", $row['current_seller_id']))){
                    $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }
        $arrItems['items'] = $seller_order_arr;`

Thanks alot @dWinder for help me and  response quickly .

Answer (score 0):

If I see that correctly, your `seller_id` value is a concatenated string of Ids. You can filter your outer array with `array_filter` and a custom callback function, which should return `true`, if the element should be kept.

```php
$idToLookup = 1;
$filteredItems = array_filter($arrItems['items'], function($element) {
    return preg_match('/(^|,)' . $idToLookup . '($|,)/', $element['seller_id']);
]);
```

Or if you are not so familiar with regex, first explode the number-string into individual numbers and then use `in_array`:

```php
$idToLookup = 1;
$filteredItems = array_filter($arrItems['items'], function($element) {
    $sellerIds = explode(',', $element['seller_id']);
    return in_array($idToLookup, $sellerIds);
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `array_filter()`

```
$array = array_filter($arrItems['items'], function ($item) {
      $ids = explode(',', $item['seller_id']);
      return in_array(1, $ids);
});
```

Comment: Your strpos attempt also find ids that contain `1` like f.e. 10 (`'seller_id' => '2,10,3'`). So this is not enough unfortunately :)

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.